# How do I diff the output of these two commands?

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, diff

I have an alias which I use to strip out comments that are piped to it:

`alias decomment='egrep -v "(^#.*|^$)"'`

I'm currently having some difficulty with a squid proxy setup, so I want to compare come config changes.  I want to use my decomment alias, as the squid.config file has a large number of commented-out lines.

How would I compare (using `diff`) the output of these two commands, in one line?

```
$ cat squid.conf.old | decomment 

$ cat squid.conf.new | decomment
```

..in the way I can this way:

```
$ cat squid.conf.old | decomment > output1

$ cat squid.conf.new | decomment > output2

$ diff output1 output2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use process substitution:

```
diff <(cat squid.conf.old | decomment) <(cat squid.conf.new | decomment)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) for this:

```
diff <(decomment < squid.conf.old) <(decomment < squid.conf.new)
```

Comment: The output is exactly the same as the other answer.  The other way is more like what I am used to and understand more, but is this answer more 'correct', as in better practice?

Comment: The other answer makes UUOC which is generally deprecated. This one IS better practice and you should get used to it.